# REGEX all character except string

Tags: regex, parsing

I need regex to parse items in text.

Structure of data is:

1. item code which contains anything
2. some optional flags AA BB CC DD
3. and quantity

I am using this regex:

```
.*\n(.+) (AA|BB|CC|DD|EE|[, ]+){0,6}(\d+).*
```

With this text string:

```
Sveiki,

I need these items:

1508-dkh-ą9 AA, BB 100
1efae 468 BB, CC 100
2efae 468 BB 100
3efae 468 100

Ačiū už dėmesį ir skirtą laiką!
```

It returns

```
<row>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <Match>1508-dkh-Ä…9 AA, BB 100</Match>
    <Group1>1508-dkh-Ä…9 AA, BB</Group1>
    <Group2></Group2>
    <Group3>100</Group3>
</row>
<row>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Match>1efae 468 BB, CC 100</Match>
    <Group1>1efae 468 BB, CC</Group1>
    <Group2></Group2>
    <Group3>100</Group3>
</row>
<row>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Match>2efae 468 BB 100</Match>
    <Group1>2efae 468 BB</Group1>
    <Group2></Group2>
    <Group3>100</Group3>
</row>
<row>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Match>3efae 468 100</Match>
    <Group1>3efae 468</Group1>
    <Group2></Group2>
    <Group3>100</Group3>
</row>
```

And I need result like this

```
<row>
    <ID>0</ID>
    <Match>1508-dkh-Ä…9 AA, BB 100</Match>
    <Group1>1508-dkh-Ä…9</Group1>
    <Group2>AA, BB</Group2>
    <Group3>100</Group3>
</row>
....
```

How can I achieve this result? (maybe there is better solution than regex?)

Comment: look into lazy quantifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you might need to modify it a bit depending on the language you are using)

```
^(.+?)([AA|BB|CC|DD|EE, ]*) ([0-9]+)$
```

The question mark in the first group will make it lazy, which will prevent it from matching your optional flags as well.

Try it out at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?375ce

Answer (score 1):

The following regex works for the example posted on the question

```
^(.+?) ((?:AA|BB|CC|DD|EE|[, ]+){0,6})(\d+)$
```